# I don't see the preview in facebook also if there are tags

Tags: facebook, open-graph-protocol, facebook-graph

My problem is that I can't see the preview in facebook also if there are "meta propriety" tags. In details in my page there are:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title">
<meta property="og:description" content="description">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://192.168.56.101:4567/sport">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.ottoetrenta.it/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/crotone-calcio.png">
<meta property="og:image:url" content="http://www.ottoetrenta.it/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/crotone-calcio.png">
```

So I go in my facebook page and I put the link "http://192.168.56.101:4567/sport". But the preview is "192.168.56.101". Anyone can help me to understand what I'm wronging?

Comment: if you are developing locally than it won't be in preview (unless you've configured you local webserver to be available from the outside world)

Answer (score 1):

192.168.56.101 is a local IP, I can't access it, and neither can Facebook.